# Hadoop - MapReduce - Cleanup after a killed job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

How can I do a cleanup for a Killed MapReduce job?

I have implemented the **commitJob()** and **abortJob()** methods of the OutputCommitter API, It seems to be working well when the job is completed successfully or when the job fails. 
but it does not work when the job is killed by the user (yarn application -kill ...)
When the job is killed by the user, **abortJob()** is not even invoked.

am I missing something? is there another way to handle killed jobs?